# How to run LLVM's built-in passes with Clang?

Tags: clang, llvm

I've noticed that LLVM provides several built-in [Analysis and Transform Passes](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html). Can I run these built-in passes (e.g., `-da` for dependency analysis) directly with `clang` instead of `opt`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, LLVM provides a mechanism to automatically register pass plugins within clang. You may need to read [here](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#building-pass-plugins)

However the above reference deals with legacy pass manager. LLVM uses the new pass manager by default for the optimization pipeline.

- [LLVM’s New Pass Manager](https://blog.llvm.org/posts/2021-03-26-the-new-pass-manager/)
- [Using the New Pass Manager](https://llvm.org/docs/NewPassManager.html)